# Codeigniter Select, Count and showing Two Dimensional Array

Tags: codeigniter, select, multidimensional-array, count

I have three tables:

```
worker_tb                        dept_tb
------------------               -----------------------
| id_worker| sex |               | id_dept | dept_name |
------------------               -----------------------
|    1     |  w  |               |    1    | Marketing |
|    2     |  m  |               |    2    | Manager   |
|    3     |  w  |               -----------------------
|    4     |  m  |
|    5     |  w  |
------------------

job_tb
--------------------------------
| id_job | id_worker | id_dept |
--------------------------------
|    1   |     1     |    1    |
|    2   |     2     |    2    |
|    3   |     3     |    2    |
|    4   |     4     |    1    |
|    5   |     5     |    1    |
--------------------------------
```

My Controller:

```php
public function count_sex()
    {
        $data['count_sex_dept'] = $this->m_worker->count_sex_dept();
        $this->load->view('count_sex', $data);
    }
```

My Model:

```php
public function count_sex_dept()
    {
        $this->db->select('*, COUNT(sex) as count_sex', FALSE);
        $this->db->from('worker_tb');
        $this->db->join('job_tb', 'job_tb.id_worker = worker_tb.id_worker');
        $this->db->join('dept_tb', 'dept_tb.id_dept = job_tb.id_dept');
        $this->db->group_by('sex');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() >0)
        {
            foreach ($query->result() as $data)
            {
                $count_sex_dept[] = $data;
            }
            return $count_sex_dept;
        }
    }
```

My View:

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
    <?php foreach($count_sex_dept as $sd) {
        if ($sd->gender == '1'){$sex = 'Man';}
        else {$sex = 'Woman';}  
    ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <label class="font-weight-bold"><?php echo $sex; ?></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <p><?php echo $sd->count_sex; ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
     <?php } ?>
</div>
```

ERROR MESSAGES:

> Error Number: 1055
>
> Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains
> nonaggregated column 'web_db2.tb_karyawan.id_kyw' which is not
> functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
> incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

But it's not working. What should I do to show this result view?

```
-----------------------------
| dept_name | male | female |
-----------------------------
| Marketing |  2   |    1   |
| Manager   |  1   |    1   |
-----------------------------
```

Comment: if you place `echo '<pre>';print_r($query->result);die;` right after `$query = $this->db->get();`, what does it output?

Comment: It's showing error message:

`Database Error

Error Number: 1055

Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'dbase.tb_worker.id_worker' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

SELECT *, COUNT(sex) as count_sex FROM `worker_tb` JOIN `job_tb` ON `job_tb`.`id_worker` = `worker_tb`.`id_worker` JOIN `dept_tb` ON `dept_tb`.`id_dept` = `worker_tb`.`id_dept` GROUP BY `sex`

Filename: C:/laragon/www/web/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691`

Comment: I think you should use GROUP BY count_sex. Also in your SELECT you should use the table name: COUNT(worker_tb.sex) as count_sex